# Right token price from liquidity

Tags: token

I have a problem regarding the price of the initial Token, I would like to insert 100 dollars of initial liquidity so as not to give the possibility to buy large quantities immediately, but I cannot find the right compromise between supply and liquidity and exit price.

Answer (score 1):

You have the flexibility to decide how much of your token supply you want to put into the liquidity pool (LP). You don't necessarily have to put your entire supply in. For example, you can choose to allocate just 1% of the token supply and add $100 to the LP.

To determine the valuation you want to maintain for your token, think about the value at which you would like it to be. Once you have that in mind, you can calculate the appropriate amount of tokens to allocate to the LP.

Let's take an example to illustrate this. Suppose you have a total of 100,000 tokens, and you aim for a mcap of $100,000. In this case, you can value each token at $1.

To achieve this valuation, you can allocate 100 tokens to the LP and add $100 in USD. This allocation would then value your entire token supply at $100,000, as per your desired mcap.